# Security for non-hr

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2010

I have noticed through Site Actions -->Site Permissions, SharePoint will allow everyone to view pages, but not every one can contribute. What I want is for users to contribute but not view certain pages. I had just linked a page back from where the users retrieve a form and update the form, but noticed these users can still view the page (they are not supposed to view), if they select the link from the main home page (human resources that is restricted for them to view). Is there a possible way for me to make the page not viewable to these users while still allowing them to make updates to the form? Can they just see the form and not the main pages? I find it strange that SharePoint has update or change form restrictions but not view/read restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably create a data view web part that shows a hyperlink to the user's form.  When clicked, it would open the form for them to edit and then dump them back to where ever they need to go.

Or you could create a filtered view of the existing document library on the main page and change the web part properties so that when the web part title is clicked, they don't go anywhere (the default behavior is to take them to the default view of the list).

Or you could create the default view of that list to be filtered so that the current owner only sees their forms.

The crux of the issue is that if a user is required to contribute, they automatically get read permissions.  You can't have contribute rights without seeing forms and application pages.

Comment: Ok, that stinks in my opinon, but then I can see why that is necessary too. I guess the best option from what you have given me is to create a default view of the list to be filtered so that the current owner only sees their forms. Also, what I noticed is when the user is taken to the form there is a button for HR (restricted site), is there a way I can disable the button and search option, so the user does not go where they don't need to be? getting these three things accomplished will allow me to be complete with this project. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @PirateEric-how do you create a default view alist to be filtered so that the current owner only sees their forms sharepoint 2010?

Comment: I don't have a 2010 system to verify the steps.  In 2007, it was navigate to the list, click the View drop down and Create a new view.  Set the view to be the default view and create a filter that filters a person/group column (like created or a promoted field from the InfoPath form) is equal to [Me].  This filters items so that only the logged in user sees their items.

Comment: You could also turn on the item level permissions in the list/library settings so that users can view only their own and edit only their own items.

Comment: Ok, so far this is what I have done was go to the list, site actions -> site permissions -> permission levels -> add a permission level -> and found a slew of different permissions. The last three permissions say they are "personal permissions", I marked 'Manage Personal Views' and selected create. When I switch to the 'test user account', i go to where the link resides that can be used for this account to update a list, access is denied. I thought using the personal views would allow this account to see what was entered on the list for this particular account. Let me try to create a new view.

Comment: I went to the list settings, but don't see the item level permissions in here. I also created a few views from the ribbon by selecting 'Create View' (Standard View). When I changed from my account to a test account, the test account was still able to view data it shouldn't. If I can disable the search bar in this site for the employee, then they can't see the list. Also, if I can remove the View site contents, then they cant see the list from there either. -sighs-

Comment: The item level permissions (in 2007) are in the Advanced Settings.  The Search and View All Site content links are easily modified by creating a new master page and hiding the search box and wrapping the View All Site Content in an elevated priviledges block.

Comment: NICE!!!!! IT WORKS! I am new to SharePoint, as you can tell. Can't get training because I'm a contractor at present, but am willing to learn! At first when I changed the settings in the Advanced Settings, I was wondering why I was able to see everyones address....duh, I'm the Farm Administrator, Administrator...then I changed to my other account and only had seen what was entered for that specific account! Then I went to 'View ALL Site Content', selected 'List Name' and still only seen what was entered for that specific account! NICE! Thank You SO MUCH!

Comment: Great, glad to be of service.  We're all noobs at some point, keep plugging away and you'll get there.